# How to append data to list everyday in R

Tags: r, statistics, append

I have made a web scraper in R using the package: "rvest" that allows me to get the average price of used vehicles from a website. However, as there are new vehicles that enters the site every day the average price changes as well.

When I run my code it first reads the URL, then gets the price, and brand of the car:

```
# Defining what URL to scrape
page = read_html("*URL*")

# Gets the title of the car (Name/ type of car)
brand = page %>% html_nodes("*css_for_car_brand*") %>% html_text()

# The price
price = page %>% html_nodes("*css_for_price*") %>% html_text()
```

After cleaning the data I put both the car brand and the price in a tibble:

```
car_data <- Tibble(brand, price)
```

Thereafter, I create a new variable so I can get the mean price for each vehicle(X):

```
Mean_brand_X <- dplyr::filter(car_data, grepl("X",brand)) %>%
summarise(mean = mean(price))
```

and so on..

I collect all the averages and put them in a new tibble:

```
Average_Car prices <- tibble(x = Mean_brand_X$mean,
                             Y = Mean_brand_Y$mean,
                             Z = Mean_brand_Y$mean)
```

or like this: (both gives same result)

```
car_data %>%
group_by(brand) %>%
summarise(mean = mean(price)) %>%
pivot_wider(values_from = mean, names_from = brand)
```

The output would look something like this:

```
    x             y              z
<dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>
470285.1    465003.6       585053.5
```

What I would like is for this data to update daily, such that I could save the averages for each day. e.g.,:

```
      Date          x           y              z
    <date>       <dbl>       <dbl>          <dbl>
08.09.2022    470285.1    465003.6       585053.5
09.09.2022    471586.1    472046.5       545955.2
```

How would I create something like this, that appends to the list every day? I feel like I could use some if statements and have the "today()" function as an argument (i.e., to determiner whether or not to create a new row with new numbers).

Thank you for any assistance you can provide; if I was not clear enough, I will provide additional information.

Comment: If you are running Windows, you can use the windows program Task Scheduler. You can make a daily task that runs your script. If you are storing your values in  text/csv/xlsx file, you should end your script with first reading the file, then appending (row binding `rbind`) the latest value, and then overwriting the file again. This would continuosly update your table (As long as the machine is running of course)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will look more into this!

Answer (score 0):

**My own solution to the problem:**

So from before my tibble looked like this:

```
      Date          x           y              z
    <date>       <dbl>       <dbl>          <dbl>
08.09.2022    470285.1    465003.6       585053.5
```

So I saved that tibble as an xlsx file using the "xlsx" package:
(lets call my tibble: "data")

```
write.xlsx(data, "thefilename.xlsx")
```

So that code allowed me to save the data as an xlsx file. Now I need to load that data back inn, and add my new data: (Lets call this: "old_data").

```
old_data <- read.xlsx(data, "thefilename.xlsx")
```

Now, I need to add some new data to "old_data". I run my program once more such that the averages gets updated. I can store this to e.g., "new_data". All i need to to now is combine the old_data and the new_data. I can do this using the rbind function:

```
rbind(old_data, new_data)
```

if i run this I will end up with a tibble like this:

```
      Date          x           y              z
    <date>       <dbl>       <dbl>          <dbl>
08.09.2022    470285.1    465003.6       585053.5
08.09.2022    475585.1    465203.6       584053.5
```

Every time i run the program it will add a new row to my tibble with new data.

By using the task scheduler for windows I managed to set up a routine that runs everyday to update the list.